# mongodb unable to create/save double-byte languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Model called **Review.rb**

```
class MovieNews::Review
        include Mongoid::Document
        include Mongoid::Timestamps
        include Mongoid::Userstamp
        include Mongoid::Search

        field :story,   type: String
end
```

When i create a instance of class review and tried saving which local language telugu in the field, im getting wrong output.

Ex1:

```
review = MovieNews::Review.new
review.story = "నటవర్గం" after pasting here it's spelling goes worng "నటవర్.."
review.save => true
```

Does Mongodb supports local languages to create collection?
Someone please help me out.

Comment: AFAICT, It is not spelled wrong, it is encoded as UTF-16 (Your first char is [0C28](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0c28/index.htm)).

Answer (score 0):

Kumar try this

```
review.story = "నటవర్గం\" after pasting here it's spelling goes worng \"నటవర్.."
```

looks like is you breaking a both moments when you use quotation marks without backslash